# parameter deduction in function template using an integer value as the template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I'm trying to implement a generic function that generates a `std::string` from an id (which is an `std::pair<uint32_,uint32_t>`).

The function is the following:

```
typedef uint32_t element_type;

template <element_type type>
std::string to_string (const std::pair<element_type, uint32_t>& id) {
    ....
    const char* name = elemen_type_traits<type>::element_type_name;
    ...
}
```

I can invoke the function in the following way:

```
std::cout << to_string<ELEMENT_TYPE_FOO> (foo_0) << std::endl;
std::cout << to_string<ELEMENT_TYPE_FOO> (foo_1) << std::endl;
```

The only thing is that I want to make sure that the template parameter matches the first field of the `std::pair`. Is it possible to deduct the parameter value from `std::pair.first`?

I don't know if it's possible but in the end I would like to have something like this:

```
std::cout << to_string (foo_0) << std::endl;
std::cout << to_string (foo_1) << std::endl;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you use the pair<> as the template argument instead of the element?

Comment: is type is actually a type? It should be a value of type uint32_t, isn't it?

Comment: @Gir I have tried that but without success. I get an error message: no matching function for call to 'to_string'

Comment: @klm123 type is a value of type_value (which is uint32_t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you encode the value inside a type, this is actually achievable:

```
// C++11 'enum class' emulation, you don't want to leak 'foo' everywhere
// also called a "scoped enum"
struct element_type_value{
   enum type{
     foo = 1337
   };
};

template<element_type_value::type V>
struct element_type{};

template<element_type_value::type V>
std::string to_string(std::pair<element_type<V>, uint32_t> const& /*id*/){
  // ...
  const char* name = element_type_traits<V>::element_type_name;
  // ...
}
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/cf2138562f108b1a34b4765c9204a8d4)

Of course, this only works if the type is always a statically known value, and actually you don't even need the `id.first` anymore. However, there's no other way of achieving this check, as far as I know.

I personally would probably drop `std::pair` and just make a custom struct, together with some other refactoring.

```
struct element_type{
   enum type{
     foo = 1337
   };
};

template<element_type::type V>
struct element_type_id{
  element_type_id(uint32_t id) : id(id){}
  uint32_t id; // or whatever your original std::pair::second represented
};

template<element_type::type V>
std::string to_string(element_type_id<V> const& /*id*/){
  // ...
  const char* name = element_type_traits<V>::element_type_name;
  // ...
}
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/0acd48d7aeb1621e6a296c2ee2569f5c)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can simply write:

```
std::string to_string (const std::pair<element_type, uint32_t>& id) {
 const element_type type = id.first;
 ....
 const char* name = elemen_type_traits<type>::element_type_name;
 ...
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work as you must know 'type' value at compilation time.

Comment: But the written is correct with respect what you want to do? Then there is no way to do it. Simply because id.first is not known at the compilation time.

Comment: That's why I'm using a template function